# Can the avro json be extened with additional information?

Tags: json, hadoop, avro

The avro format is used in hadoop as a header to describe the contents of the binary file that follows.  My question is whether the json part of the avro file can be extended to include information that is not necessary for hadoop?  The typical use case would be to attach meta-data like the originator of the file and a date to the file without it needing to be data and part of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Avro files can be annotated with additional information in the json schema or with specific additional name:value pairs.  Additionally, we have been able to read these avro files with Pentaho and Google Big Query.  One caveat is that the schema and name:value pairs are discarded during the import process.  So if you feel you will need them later, you should extract and store local copies of them.